# Jackson parse string field as JSON

Tags: java, jackson

I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "some_key": "{\"a\": 1, \"b\": \"text\"}"
}
```

As you can see `some_key` field is not a JSON object it is a string, that contains valid JSON.

I would like to parse it into following structure:

```
class Foo {
    Bar some_key;
}

class Bar {
    int a;
    String b;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

- class A and B, has getters and setters, constructors. I haven't show
  them to keep sample short and simple.
- I can't edit the weird structure of the JSON.
- The question is how to ask Jackson parse the inner string field as
  JSON object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@t_liang is very close - just need a bit more room than a comment to show the working example...

With:

```
class Foo {
    @JsonDeserialize(using = BarDeserializer.class)
    private Bar some_key;
}
```

Then the current `ObjectMapper` is actually the `JsonParser.getCodec()`:

```
public class BarDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Bar> {
    @Override
    public Bar deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String text = p.getText();
        ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) p.getCodec();
        return mapper.readValue(text, Bar.class);
    }
}
```

Then this...

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

Foo foo = mapper.readValue(
        "{ \"some_key\": \"{\\\"a\\\": 1, \\\"b\\\": \\\"text\\\"}\" }",
        Foo.class);

System.out.println(foo.getSome_key());
```

... shows the expected value:

```
Bar [a=1, b=text]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But that cast to `ObjectMapper` doesn't seem good to me. I've found a way to avoid it: create a `JsonParser` using `ObjectCodec.getFactory().createParser(...)` and pass it to `ObjectCodec.readValue(...)`. See https://pastebin.com/M22CsAAd

Answer (score 4):

```
step 1:
public class BarDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Bar> {
    @Override
    public Bar deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String text = p.getText();
        return <your ObjectMapper>.readValue(text, Bar.class);
    }
}

step 2:
class Foo {
    @JsonDeserialize(using=BarDeserializer.class)
    Bar some_key;
}
or
@JsonDeserialize(using=BarDeserializer.class)
class Bar {
    int a;
    String b;
}
```

Comment: How can current `ObjectMapper` be accessed inside `deserialize()`?

Comment: Using the same `ObjectMapper` will result in the `StackOverflowError`, won't it?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems:

- `json` provided in example does not correspond to the schema. E.g. as per `json`, `some_key` is a String field (it's wrapped in double quotes) whereas as per schema, it's a `Boo` field. You need to change json to look like following (Or change `some_value` to String type):

  `{
      "some_key": {\"a\": 1, \"b\": \"text\"}
  }`
- There are no getters or setters. `Jackson` can't deserialize can't access getters/setters via reflection.

Here's the working example:

```
class Foo {

    Bar some_key;

    public Bar getSome_key() {
        return some_key;
    }

    public void setSome_key(Bar some_key) {
        this.some_key = some_key;
    }

}

class Bar {
    int a;
    String b;
    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }
    public void setA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }
    public void setB(String b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

Deserialization:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Foo response = mapper.readValue("{\"some_key\": {\"a\": 1, \"b\": \"text\"}}", Foo.class);
```

Comment: I didn't add getters and setters to keep sample short.

Comment: Okay, in that case, it should work after removing brackets around `some_key` value.

Comment: My problem is that I can't remove bracket's.

Comment: Sorry, I meant double quotes and not brackets

Comment: I also meant double quotes. The problem is that the real json is big and some of the inner models have such structure.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. Putting together *Vladimir Petrakovich*'s comment and a bit of research I arrived at a solution that seems to work for any class, including yours (I used Java 17, but it should also work with earlier versions):

```
public class JSONStringDeserializer<T> extends JsonDeserializer<T> implements ContextualDeserializer {
  private JavaType contextualType;

  @Override
  public T deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt)
      throws IOException {
    try (JsonParser parser = p.getCodec().getFactory().createParser(p.getText())) {
      return p.getCodec().readValue(parser, this.contextualType);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public JsonDeserializer<?> createContextual(DeserializationContext deserializationContext, BeanProperty beanProperty) throws JsonMappingException {
    this.contextualType = beanProperty.getType();
    return this;
  }
}
```

This solution solve your problem. However it does not work correctly for *n* levels of nesting, i.e. if the JSON-formatted string itself contains a JSON-formatted string, the deserialisation fails. In other words, in the following JUnit 5 test class (which uses [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) annotations to shorten the code) `test_json_string_deserializer()` succeeds while `test_json_string_deserializer_nested()` fails. Of course any contribution is welcome.

```
class JSONStringDeserializerTest {

  @Test
  void test_json_string_deserializer() {
    try {
      /* Arrange */
      ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
      String jsonDto = """
          {
              "some_key": "{\\"a\\": 1, \\"b\\": \\"text\\"}",
              "some_other_key": "{\\"x\\": 123, \\"y\\": 1, \\"z\\": \\"text\\"}"
          }""";

      /* Act */
      Foo parsedDto = objectMapper.readValue(jsonDto, Foo.class);

      /* Assert */
      Foo expectedDto = Foo.builder()
          .some_key(Bar.builder()
              .a(1)
              .b("text")
              .build())
          .some_other_key(SomethingElse.builder()
              .x(123)
              .y((byte) 1)
              .z("text")
              .build())
          .build();
      assertThat(parsedDto).isEqualTo(expectedDto);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
      fail("Failed to deserialize Foo", e);
    }
  }

  @Test
  void test_json_string_deserializer_nested() {
    try {
      /* Arrange */
      ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
      String jsonDto = """
          {
            "description":"Example Description",
            "nested":"{\\"details\\": \\"{\\"id\\": 12345}\\"}",
            "alertState":"Active"
          }""";

      /* Act */
      BeanDTO parsedDto = objectMapper.readValue(jsonDto, BeanDTO.class);

      /* Assert */
      BeanDTO expectedDto = BeanDTO.builder()
          .description("Example Description")
          .nested(NestedBeanDTO.builder()
              .details(NestedNestedBeanDTO.builder()
                  .id(12345L)
                  .build())
              .build())
          .alertState("Active")
          .build();
      assertThat(parsedDto).isEqualTo(expectedDto);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
      fail("Failed to deserialize BeanDTO", e);
    }
  }

  @Data
  @Builder
  @Jacksonized
  static class Foo {
    @JsonDeserialize(using = JSONStringDeserializer.class)
    Bar some_key;

    @JsonDeserialize(using = JSONStringDeserializer.class)
    SomethingElse some_other_key;
  }

  @Data
  @Builder
  @Jacksonized
  static class Bar {
    int a;
    String b;
  }

  @Data
  @Builder
  @Jacksonized
  static class SomethingElse {
    long x;
    byte y;
    String z;
  }

  @Data
  @Builder
  @Jacksonized
  static class BeanDTO {
    private String description;

    @JsonDeserialize(using = JSONStringDeserializer.class)
    private NestedBeanDTO nested;

    private String alertState;
  }

  @Data
  @Builder
  @Jacksonized
  static class NestedBeanDTO {
    @JsonDeserialize(using = JSONStringDeserializer.class)
    private NestedNestedBeanDTO details;
  }

  @Data
  @Builder
  @Jacksonized
  static class NestedNestedBeanDTO {
    private Long id;
  }
}
```

Comment: Pardon me, but it's not clear whether you are posting a solution or asking another question. Are you saying that your code solves the problem described in the question but with limitations? Or are you asking for someone to improve your code so as to overcome those limitations?

Comment: @Abra Sorry, allow me to clarify: the proposed solution solves the problem in the scenario proposed in the question, i.e. in a scenario where you have a JSON with one or more string fields in JSON format WITHOUT having string fields in JSON format within them. I was not explicitly asking for help to improve the solution, I merely said that anyone who feels able is welcome.
I hope it is now clearer, thank you for your comment